# How to use keyboard key press popup menu

Tags: ios, keyboard

What is that control? Or how to achieve this function?
[circled area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHfkq.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cQJC.png]

Comment: There is no standard control for that. Write your own or find one on github or other location.

Comment: Its default feature i think in iOS.